# GZIP base64 NSString

Tags: ios, macos, compression, base64, gzip

I'm using this [GZIP library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP) to compress my base64 image string on osx and then sending it to iOS where I want to unzip and present. I have no luck with compression. I tried to convert NSString to NSData, then I compress it, after that I make string of it again.
In iOS I do this backwards but image is not working. Any other solution for compression, or for base64 compressing ?

Comment: Can you give more detail? Do you know the point of failure? Did you test with something simple like a text string?

Comment: I tried and it returns `nil` when I'm converting gzipped data into string.

Comment: I would write the output to a file on the mac side and try to unzip it outside of code. That way we can eliminate the compression phase as a problem. If it works you need to look at the send. Can you send a block of cleartext and get it on the iOS side correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you compress a base64 encoded image? - Just transfer the unencoded image.

image (binary, highly compressed) -> base64 (plaintext 3x size) -> gzip (compressed binary)

Just don't encode the Image with base64 or decode it into its normal binary form.

Comment: Well base64 ratio is 4:3, so it is not 300% of original, but 133%. I need it to be prepared for receiving images from windows later. Is there any other way to encode image on windows so it will be presentable on iOS ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Image"? - surely it will be some jpeg binary or similar. Just send that over the wire. Also you refer to "sending" which does not make clear how you are doing that, does the method require plaintext like json or xml ?